# Problems with using C++ Shared Object with Android Studio

Tags: java, c++, android-studio, shared-libraries

I am trying to understand how android studio works with Shared Libraries ".so" file.  Their simple Hello World with C++ works fine but I am working on porting a large set of C++ code to android and want to understand the easiest way to do it.  I don't necessarily want to add the CMakeLists.txt file to Android Studio since some of the code is not build using cmake.

What I have done is created two projects in Android Studio.  Hello World CPP with C++ support and it works fine.  I have also created a Hello World Java (without the C++) support.

My goal was to take the libnative-lib.so files created in the Hello World CPP project, copy them over to the Hello World Java and change the Java code to reference the stringFromJNI() function.

In the Java version, I have created the apps/src/main/jniLibs directory and copied over the entire directory ./app/build/intermediates/transforms/mergeJniLibs/debug/0/lib/ from the CPP version.  These are the files that I brought over.

~/AndroidStudioProjects/HelloJava/app/src/main/jniLibs$ ls -R 
.:
arm64-v8a  armeabi-v7a  x86  x86_64

./arm64-v8a:
libnative-lib.so

./armeabi-v7a:
libnative-lib.so

./x86:
libnative-lib.so

./x86_64:
libnative-lib.so

I then went back to the MainActivity class in the Java version and copied over the

```
  static {
        System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
    }
```

and added the following to the end of the onCreate.  (I added the ID to the layout so R.id.sample_text is valid.)

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sample_text);
tv.setText(stringFromJNI());
```

Build works fine but when I try to run on an AVD, I get the following error.

```
E/.gary.hellojav: No implementation found for java.lang.String com.example.gary.hellojava.MainActivity.stringFromJNI() (tried Java_com_example_gary_hellojava_MainActivity_stringFromJNI and Java_com_example_gary_hellojava_MainActivity_stringFromJNI__)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
```

I have removed the stringFromJNI call and it runs fine in the AVD.  I have changed the library name in the loadLibrary call to something invalid and loadLibrary throws an exception so it seems like it finds the library, I just can't resolve the stringFromJNI name quite right.

Any suggestions or obvious oversight on my part?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.  The issue in the the native-lib.cpp file, the fully qualified name was incorrect when I move from one project to the next since the project name was imbedded in the stringFromJNI.  I needed to change

```
Java_com_example_gary_hcpp_MainActivity_stringFromJNI
```

to

```
Java_com_example_gary_hjava_MainActivity_stringFromJNI
```